# Adding subviews on a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitoolbar, autolayout

I'm working on a project were I use mostly UITableViews. The user enters data and the App gives the result of a calculation. I have two buttons: "Calculate" and "Reset". I want to add a subview containing these two buttons and have them displayed at the bottom of the screen. By Storyboards, I can add the subview, but it sticks to the button of the UITableView, not the screen.

Any idea on how to accomplish that? Should I mess with the constrains between the subview with the buttons and self.tableview.superview ?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using TableViewController in storyboard? If you are, dont. Use View Controller and add tableview to your view controller. Make the delegate and datasource connections. Adjust its size and put your buttons in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController, and add a UITableView to your view controller. You can then place subviews at will.

Do not forget to connect datasource and delegate of your tableview.